# Node.js Express App- User Log in & Register Error

Tags: node.js, express

I am **totally new** to node.js and Express. I'd like to build an app with user management. I've consulted the **stormpath** site (https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app)
and the app built and shown as below:

[The Welcome Page Screen shot](https://ibb.co/i3WoWF)

When I click the **Register now** and **Login now** , the error occurs:

[The Register Error Screen shot](https://ibb.co/kCSvBF)

I'm totally followed the tutorial, and the **server.js** is as below:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

 var app = express();

 app.set('views', './views');
 app.set('view engine', 'jade');

 app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
 expand: {
    customData: true
   }
}));

app.get('/', stormpath.getUser, function(req, res) {
res.render('home', {
  title: 'Welcome'
   });
});

app.use('/profile',stormpath.loginRequired,require('./profile')());
app.on('stormpath.ready',function(){
console.log('Stormpath Ready');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

the **index.jade** is as below:

```
html
head
title=title
link(href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', 
rel='stylesheet')
body
 div.container
  div.jumbotron
    h1 Release Control System

    if user
      p Welcome, #{user.fullName}
      p
        a.small(href="profile") Edit my profile
      form(action='/logout', method='POST')
        button.btn.btn-default(type="submit") Logout
    else
      p Welcome to the release control system , please log in to get started.
      p
        a.btn.btn-primary(href="/login") Login now
      p
        span.small Don't have an account?
        span &nbsp;
        a.small(href="/register") Register now
```

and the **paackage.json**,

```
  {
   "name": "sampple",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
   "dependencies": {
   "body-parser": "~1.16.0",
   "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
   "debug": "~2.6.0",
   "express": "~4.14.1",
   "jade": "~1.11.0",
   "morgan": "~1.7.0",
   "serve-favicon": "~2.3.2"
  },
   "description": "Release control",
   "main": "server.js",
   "devDependencies": {},
   "author": "",
   "license": "MIT"
  }
```

Kindly advise where should be revised in order to fix the error, including press the "Login now" button.

Any advise is appreciated since I'm not familiar with node.js and Express framework and I'd like to achieve user management, thanks.

Comment: you should try adding a route like this : 

`app.get('/profile',(req,res)=>{ res.render('profile');});`

The stormpath link you provided use a router to handle their route that's why they can call `app.use('/profile',....);`

But since you don't use this router ... there is nothing to manage this.

Comment: Actually, just by requiring in express-stormpath and adding app.on('stormpath.ready...), you automatically get the /register, /login, /me, and a bunch of other routes and views.

Comment: @mdegges, what's " requiring in express-stormpath "? Would you please explain more? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. You need to 1) npm install express-stormpath, 2) add var stormpath = require('express-stormpath'); to your server file, 3) optionally configure stormpath with app.use(stormpath.init(app, {...})), and 4) do app.on('stormpath.ready'...). This is covered in the express-stormpath quickstart: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/setup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Stormpath. There is minimal setup required to get express-stormpath working with your Application. Once you `npm install express-stormpath` and add `var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');`, you just need to do two more things:

```
// Tell your express app to use Stormpath
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  // Add optional configuration settings here
  expand: { 
    customData: true
  }
}));

// Wait for Stormpath to tell you it's ready
app.on('stormpath.ready',function(){
  console.log('Stormpath Ready');
});
```

Once you do these steps, you'll automatically get the /register, /login, /me, /verify, and /forgot routes (and default views for these routes) right out of the box. This is covered in our quickstart, which you can follow here: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/setup.html

[This tutorial](https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app) explains how to set up a really basic express project that has one extra view, a profile page for logged in users. The below is the code directly copy/pasted from the tutorial. Let me know if this works for you.

server.js:

```
var express = require('express'); var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

var app = express();

app.set('views', './views'); app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(stormpath.init(app, {   expand: {
    customData: true   } }));

app.get('/', stormpath.getUser, function(req, res) {   res.render('home', {
    title: 'Welcome'   }); });

app.on('stormpath.ready',function(){   console.log('Stormpath Ready'); });

app.listen(3000);
```

profile.js:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var csurf = require('csurf');
var express = require('express');
var extend = require('xtend');
var forms = require('forms');

var collectFormErrors = require('express-stormpath/lib/helpers').collectFormErrors;

// Declare the schema of our form:

var profileForm = forms.create({
  givenName: forms.fields.string({
    required: true
  }),
  surname: forms.fields.string({ required: true }),
  streetAddress: forms.fields.string(),
  city: forms.fields.string(),
  state: forms.fields.string(),
  zip: forms.fields.string()
});

// A render function that will render our form and
// provide the values of the fields, as well
// as any situation-specific locals

function renderForm(req,res,locals){
  res.render('profile', extend({
    title: 'My Profile',
    csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
    givenName: req.user.givenName,
    surname: req.user.surname,
    streetAddress: req.user.customData.streetAddress,
    city: req.user.customData.city,
    state: req.user.customData.state,
    zip: req.user.customData.zip
  },locals||{}));
}

// Export a function which will create the
// router and return it

module.exports = function profile(){

  var router = express.Router();

  router.use(cookieParser());

  router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

  router.use(csurf({ cookie: true }));

  // Capture all requests, the form library will negotiate
  // between GET and POST requests

  router.all('/', function(req, res) {
    profileForm.handle(req,{
      success: function(form){
        // The form library calls this success method if the
        // form is being POSTED and does not have errors

        // The express-stormpath library will populate req.user,
        // all we have to do is set the properties that we care
        // about and then cal save() on the user object:
        req.user.givenName = form.data.givenName;
        req.user.surname = form.data.surname;
        req.user.customData.streetAddress = form.data.streetAddress;
        req.user.customData.city = form.data.city;
        req.user.customData.state = form.data.state;
        req.user.customData.zip = form.data.zip;
        req.user.customData.save();
        req.user.save(function(err){
          if(err){
            if(err.developerMessage){
              console.error(err);
            }
            renderForm(req,res,{
              errors: [{
                error: err.userMessage ||
                err.message || String(err)
              }]
            });
          }else{
            renderForm(req,res,{
              saved:true
            });
          }
        });
      },
      error: function(form){
        // The form library calls this method if the form
        // has validation errors.  We will collect the errors
        // and render the form again, showing the errors
        // to the user
        renderForm(req,res,{
          errors: collectFormErrors(form)
        });
      },
      empty: function(){
        // The form library calls this method if the
        // method is GET - thus we just need to render
        // the form
        renderForm(req,res);
      }
    });
  });

  // This is an error handler for this router

  router.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // This handler catches errors for this router
    if (err.code === 'EBADCSRFTOKEN'){
      // The csurf library is telling us that it can't
      // find a valid token on the form
      if(req.user){
        // session token is invalid or expired.
        // render the form anyways, but tell them what happened
        renderForm(req,res,{
          errors:[{error:'Your form has expired.  Please try again.'}]
        });
      }else{
        // the user's cookies have been deleted, we dont know
        // their intention is - send them back to the home page
        res.redirect('/');
      }
    }else{
      // Let the parent app handle the error
      return next(err);
    }
  });

  return router;
};
```

views/home.jade:

```
html
  head
    title=title
    link(href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
  body
    div.container
      div.jumbotron
        h1 Hello!

        if user
          p Welcome, #{user.fullName}
          p
            a.small(href="profile") Edit my profile
          form(action='/logout', method='POST')
            button.btn.btn-default(type="submit") Logout
        else
          p Welcome to my app, ready to get started?
          p
            a.btn.btn-primary(href="/login") Login now
          p
            span.small Don't have an account?
            span &nbsp;
            a.small(href="/register") Register now
```

views/profile.jade:

```
html
  head
    title=title
    link(
      href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css',
      rel='stylesheet'
    )
  body
    div.container

      div.page-header
        h1 My Profile

      if errors
        each error in errors
          div.alert.alert-danger
            span #{error.error}
      if saved
        div.alert.alert-success
          span Your profile has been saved
      form.login-form.form-horizontal(method='post', role='form')
        input(name='_csrf', type='hidden', value=csrfToken)

        div.form-group
          label.col-sm-4 First Name
          div.col-sm-8
            input.form-control(
              placeholder='Your first name',
              required=true,
              name='givenName',
              type='text',
              value=givenName)
        div.form-group
          label.col-sm-4 Last Name
          div.col-sm-8
            input.form-control(placeholder='Your last name',
              required=true,
              name='surname',
              type='text',
              value=surname)
        div.form-group
          label.col-sm-4 Street address
          div.col-sm-8
            input.form-control(placeholder='e.g. 123 Sunny Ave',
              required=true,
              name='streetAddress',
              type='text',
              value=streetAddress)
        div.form-group
          label.col-sm-4 City
          div.col-sm-8
            input.form-control(placeholder='e.g. City',
              required=true,
              name='city',
              type='text',
              value=city)
        div.form-group
          label.col-sm-4 State
          div.col-sm-8
            input.form-control(placeholder='e.g. CA',
              required=true,
              name='state',
              type='text',
              value=state)
        div.form-group
          label.col-sm-4 ZIP
          div.col-sm-8
            input.form-control(placeholder='e.g. 94116',
              required=true,
              name='zip',
              type='text',
              value=zip)
        div.form-group
          div.col-sm-offset-4.col-sm-8
            button.login.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Save
        div.pull-right
          a(href="/") Return to home page
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the same tutorial I followed; after following your steps the same error still occurs. And I cannot find /register, /login, /me, /verify in my folder.

Comment: I downloaded apiKey.properties file, but do not know how to save it to the following location in home directory: ~/.stormpath/apiKey.properties

Comment: @Samoth You will get a 401 error when you run ``node server.js`` if you haven't set your environment variables correctly. You can set them directly in your terminal right before you start your server like this: ````export STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID=xxx
export STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET=xxx
export STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF=xxx
```` Make sure that you replace 'xxx' with your actual API key ID, secret, and Application href. If you're on a windows machine, try 'set' instead of 'export'

Comment: The /register, /login, /me, and other provided routes will not be visible to you (as they included with the library). If you follow the steps above and set your environment variables, you will be able to navigate to localhost:3000/register, /login, etc.

Comment: thanks. I set the environment variables but the **404** error still occurs. And I checked the /register, /login, /me, and other provided routes are correctly installed: `C:\Users\user\sampple2\node_modules\express-stormpath\lib`.

Comment: I navigate to localhost:3000 via my company's proxy settings, I think it might be Stormpath is banned from my company's network?

Comment: And under my app path, I entered the command: `node server.js`, and the error message: `Unable to execute http request GET my app HREF`; when entered the command: `npm start`, I can see the welcome page but cannot still access to *login* and *register* page.

Comment: @Samoth are you able to successfully make a simple curl request? An example request can be found here: https://support.stormpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/221029667-Where-can-I-find-my-Tenant-ID-and-Tenant-Name-

Comment: I made a GET request with my tenant API key to **https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/current** and it return a json format outpu as follow: `{"href":"https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/6wEjuNpnaE36JR94z7OXUa","name":"powerful-knife","key":"powerful-knife","createdAt":"2017-02-08T01:35:36.728Z","modifiedAt":"2017-02-08T01:35:38.228Z","customData":{"href":"https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/6wEjuNpnaE36JR94z7OXUa/customData"},"organizations":{"href":"https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/6wEjuNpnaE36JR94z7OXUa/organizations"},

Comment: I am not sure does this mean I made a successful request and the connection is okay even I used my company's networking behind the proxy.